# How to capture response from child process in nodejs

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am trying to capture some response from my child process in master process. I can log information of child process in master process but unable to capture some return xyz response .
Here is code for master process:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app = express();
const
             fs = require('fs'),
             cp = require('child_process');
 app.get('/',onRequest );
    function onRequest(request, response) {
                var express  = require('express');
             var app = express();

            var child= cp.spawn('node' ,['./child_process/block.js'],filestreamCallback);
            child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
                console.log('stdout: ==== ' + data);
            });
            child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
                console.log('stdout: ' + data);
            });
            child.on('close', function(code) {
                console.log('closing code: ' + code);
            });
        function filestreamCallback() {
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                baflog.info("Reading Stream completed");
                response.write('Thanks for Your patience!\n');
                response.end();
            }
        }
        app.listen(5000);
        console.log('Server started');

Child process : block.js

        /*Keep waiting for 10 seconds*/

    console.log("Waiting for child Process (block.js) to complete......");
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + 10000);
    ret_resp();
    var response = {status:'success'};
    function ret_resp(){
        return response;
    }
    console.log("Thank You for waiting......");
```

Like in console i see output as : 
stdout====:  Waiting for child Process (block.js) to complete......
 -punws-sohan

stdout: ====  Thank You for waiting......

I cannot see output for return response statement 
Can anyone suggest how to capture response from child process?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the busy loop uses up unnecessary CPU time. Just use a `setTimeout()` instead. Example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  ret_resp();
  // ...
}, 10000);
```

Secondly, you can't expect `return` to magically write the returned value to the parent process. Try this instead:

```
// parent.js
var child = cp.fork('./child_process/block.js', [], { silent: true });
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('stdout: ==== ' + data);
});
child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
child.on('message', function(msg) {
  console.log('message from child: ' + require('util').inspect(msg));
});
child.on('close', function(code) {
  console.log('closing code: ' + code);
});


// child.js
console.log('Waiting for child Process (block.js) to complete......');
setTimeout(function() {
  var response = {status:'success'};
  function ret_resp() {
    process.send(response);
  }
  ret_resp();
  console.log('Thank You for waiting......');
}, 10000);
```

Comment: You are wrapping the message in  log , i dont want to do that. I want to like we do in fork. process.send(msg) then master process receives the message. Its possible with fork but i cannot see way with spawn/exec .

Comment: I am getting error 
child_process.js:402
      throw new TypeError('message cannot be undefined');
            ^
TypeError: message cannot be undefined
    at process.target.send (child_process.js:402:13)
    at ret_resp (d:\Node Js\baflog\child_process\block.js:16:17)
    at null._onTimeout (d:\Node Js\baflog\child_process\block.js:13:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)

closing code: 8

Comment: Great,thanks for help. As i am new to node js can you also add for me how can i exit the fork process, as i can see process is running continuously. ow or when shold i end?

Comment: Also i would like to ask , is it possible to send reposnes when the process are spawned? If i dont want to use fork still i can send reposne?

Comment: The child process shouldn't continue running once it has written "Thank You for waiting......" to stdout. You can't use `message` event handlers and `.send()` with ordinary `spawn()` or `exec()`. `fork()` is merely [a special case of `spawn()`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7f86baf5c7713b6bd541b549352795fe8a55b9de/lib/child_process.js#L521-L545) that uses an extra fd for IPC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60409/discussion-between-sohan-and-mscdex).

Comment: Please see my updated code in question. Now how can i use fork and exit the process?